# Geocode get Latitude and Longitude from address

Tags: java, android, arraylist, geocoding

I have tryed to get latitude and longitude from address in ArrayList , and write latitude and longitude in another Arraylist. It doesn't work.
In ArrayList User is Address of User,
In ArrayList latlon is latitude and longitude.

```
Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
        Iterator<User>ite=Profile.User.listIterator();
        List<Address>address;
        User temp=null;
        int br=0;
        while(ite.hasNext()){
            temp=ite.next();
            address=coder.getFromLocationName(temp.Useraddress,1);
            Address location = address.get(br);
            UserLocation.latlon.add(new latlon(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
            br++;
        }
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Do you get an exception? If so, can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Do you mean that `latlon` is empty? One obvious problem with your code is that if there is more than one User, `br` will be `1` on the second iteration of the loop, but `address` will only ever have at most one element, because you specify you only want one result (that's the second argument to `coder.getFromLocationName`). If you only want one address, you should use `Address location = address.get(0)`.

Comment: yes it's empty. One User with more Address.

Comment: Do you mean that you only want to search for the address of a single user, but get multiple possible results (Addresses) back?

Comment: @MilanA11 can you print the values during every iteration. Lets see what's the exact problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I'm providing you sample code for fetching lat/long from address. Try this :

```
 Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
 List<Address> address;

 try {
 address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress,5);
 if (address == null) {
     return null;
 }
 Address location = address.get(0);
 lat = location.getLatitude();
 lng = location.getLongitude();

}
```